# Parsing JSON into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json, parsing

I'm fetching data from an API, and one of properties of the data is a description of the item, but the `JSON` response is written in `HTML`, and  has `<a></a>` tags and other html elements in it. I would like to NOT display the tags and have them actually work.

for example, this is what its output to the screen:

"Here is the `<a href='https://www.google.com'> Link </a>`"

This is what it should look like:

"Here is the  Link "

How can I achieve this?

*(I'm using Next.js)*

and this is how I'm displaying the data

`<p>{description}</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below. `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is the `JSX` property you need.

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: description }}></p>
```

Check the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) for more info

**Working example**

```js
function App() {

  const description = "Here is the <a href='https://www.google.com'> Link </a>"; 

  return (
    <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: description }}></p>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: @Eric Pezzulo, check this out!!